# How to make `ncdu` show a quick summary of disk usage and exit?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, ncurses, du

I'd like to make the `ncdu` NCurses Disk Usage tool analyze a path, display the output, and exit, for scripting purposes. Normally it is a human-interactive tool, but I'd like to remove the human-interactive part of it.

If I run `ncdu /boot` I can see my `/boot` partition. Here is what I see:

```
ncdu 1.14.1 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help 
--- /boot -----------------------------------------------------
  100.2 MiB [##########]  initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic         
  100.2 MiB [######### ]  initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
   11.2 MiB [#         ]  vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic
    8.0 MiB [          ] /grub
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-25-generic
    5.6 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.11.0-46-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-28-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-27-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-25-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.11.0-46-generic
  184.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
  184.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+.elf
  180.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+.bin
!  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
!   4.0 KiB [          ] /efi
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

Now, how can I script this to display this output, store it into a variable for later printing, and exit?

What I'd like is something like this:

```bsh
output="$(ncdu /boot)"
echo "$output"
```

Currently it hangs at the first line since it's waiting on human interaction I think.

Follow-on question: [bash: make `du` show output similar to `ncdu`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689668/bash-make-du-show-output-similar-to-ncdu)

Comment: I guess if `ncdu` has no option for it, it won't be possible. It can return `json` string with `ncdu -o- /boot`

Comment: @pLumo, well, it's a computer. There's _always_ a way. It may just require a little bit of craziness. Ex: have the program screenshot the output, run OCR on it, move the mouse like a human, press keyboard keys, etc. Granted, that would be a very non-ideal solution.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question at the end of the question.

Comment: What does this question have to do with the unstated version of Ubuntu you use?

Comment: @David, probably nothing. Should I move the question to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, by the way, but all that would change is the version of `ncdu`, in case it has come out with new options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ncdu`, it is not possible. It uses `ncurses` library to display the results with interactive features and (unlike e.g. `top` with `-b` option) it has no direct option to print what it displays.

However, it can print (or save to file) a `json` with all information you need, that can be parsed: `ncdu -o file.json` or to stdout: `ncdu -o-`.

I provided a `python` script to parse this to a similar output over at [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689673/236063).

Comment: Use `ncdu -f file.json` to read

  -o FILE                    Export scanned directory to FILE
  -f FILE                    Import scanned directory from FILE

Answer (score 2):

the `ncdu` [webpage](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) lists similar projects at the bottom, one of being [tdu](https://github.com/dundee/gdu) "top disk usage" that does exit non-interactively with a text summary (including biggest nested files). Another [gdu](https://github.com/dundee/gdu) does have  both - ncurses interface and non-interactive exit built-in.